# How to Compute the hash value for the specified byte array

Tags: asp.net, actionscript-3, apache-flex, encryption, hash

How Can I Compute the hash value for the specified byte array In **`ActionScript`** Which Is  Done in **`C# / VB`** with [ComputeHash(Byte())](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.computehash%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and its Detail is [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

How can I use **`ComputeHash(byte())`** in **ACtionScript**

Any Help Is Greatly Admired

Thank You

Udit bhardwaj

Answer (score 1):

It pretty much depends on what hash do you want to get. Base64 encoder that will convert ByteArray to base64 encoded String:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/Base64Encoder.html

Depending on your content, you can also use
[http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#toString()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#toString%28%29)

As well as [http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#readUTFBytes()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#readUTFBytes%28%29)

It's up to you to chose :)